# ajax GET json data sending to controller problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm calling

```
$.get('/profile', {'data_id': 0}, null, 'script');
```

in my `profile/index.html.haml` when a specific event happens. This is suppose to load `profile/index.js.erb` while passing the json data.  In my profile controller's `index` action, I have

```
@dataid = params[:data_id]
if @dataid == 0
  #do something, ie set variables that index.js.erb needs
else
  #do something else
end
```

However, the `if` statement doesn't seem to work so because of that I believe my `js.erb` file is not loading right (doesn't load at all).

However if I do `if !dataid.nil?` instead of `== 0 (or some other value)`, it works like before putting in the if statement/js.erb works so it must be getting that dataid is *some* value...

Also if I don't use the `if` statement, and in my `js.erb` I do `dataid = <%= raw @dataid %>; alert(dataid);`, everything loads fine and the alert is correct--dataid is 0. So why is it it seems like the controller that sets the `raw @dataid` in the first place doesn't know what `@dataid`'s value is? I'm very confused...

The main purpose was to not do everything in the controller unless needed (as specified by data_id). Also this way I thought I'd be able to do the same in my js.erb--only run the sections that I need based on this parameter.

Comment: Perhaps the value is `"0"` not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that comes via HTTP will arrive as a string. If you compare with "0", it will most likely compare equal. Try this in your controller code:

```
Rails.logger.debug "All params are:\n#{params.inspect}"
Rails.logger.debug "I got params[:data_id] = '#{@dataid}'"
Rails.logger.debug "The type is: #{@dataid.class}"
Rails.logger.debug "Comparison yields: #{@dataid == 0}"
```

Then watch the logs. You'll see what I'm talking about.